# After press back from splash screen app goes to previous open activity android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

In my application when user open app by click "app icon" then screen open by this flow

SplashActivity -> WelcomeActivity -> SignInActivity

when user open app by click "some link" then screen flow is

Splashactivity -> VideoActivity

when I open app by click "some link" then screen flow is same as above

Splashactivity -> VideoActivity

but when i press back in splash activity in this condition app goes to "SignInActivity" instead of close the app

manifest for Splash, Welcome, video activity

```
//splash
 <activity
            android:name=".splash.SplashActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:host="tinyurl.com"
                    android:scheme="https" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>

//video
<activity
            android:name=".videocall.ui.VideoActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />


//welcome
<activity
            android:name=".videocall.ui.WelcomeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />


//SignIn
<activity
            android:name=".videocall.ui.SignInActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

I open Welcome activity from splash screen by this

```
 val intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, WelcomeActivity::class.java)
                    intent.flags = intent.flags or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()
```

So If I first open app by icon and goes to sign in activity and then put app in background and open app by click some link then If i press back button while I'm in splash screen then app need to be close not open sign in activity

So please tell me what to do in this situation

Comment: First get rid of the special launch mode `singleTask`. This isn't necessary and causes more problems than it solves. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your activity stack:

```
Spash -> Welcome -> Sign-in
```

After open by link

```
Sign-in -> Splash -> Video
```

Because your app in background and the last activity is Sign-in.

How about if we use `finish()` in `onBackPress` of `SplashAcitivity`?

Comment: Yes i understand app is in background but I want app close on back click in splash screen
and I try finish in onbackpress in splashscreen but still sign in show

Comment: finish is close splashactivity not clear back stack in which sign in is available

Comment: You right, that's my mistake, you can use method `finishAffinity()` instead `finish`. That method will close all activity in stack below SplashActivity.